# iphone custom animation with a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I use a UINavigationController for scrolling some contents in my App. At one point I don't want the controller to fade in the new table from the side, I want it to fade in from bottom. How can I do this?

If that is not possible, Im looking for a way to remove the child element of the UINavigationController without the standard fade out to the left, which gets executed by pressing the back arrow on the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not use UINavigationController then.  You can make your own subclass of UIViewController that shows other view controllers or views through transitions you control.  A modal view controller can be made to slide in from the bottom for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is too much work to make everything behave like a Navigation Controller, without actually using this class...